# How to check the specific files(file_names) are there in the directory using Batch script

Tags: csv, echo

I am trying to find the specific files, which exists or not there in the directory using Batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal
CD C:\MM-cmd\INPUT

for /r %%i in (*.csv) do set var=%%i( 

echo %var%
)
```

it's not getting filenames.

it's printing like:

```
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

Can anyone help me please?!

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). But why don't you just `echo %%i`?

Comment: thanks Stephan for suggestion
if i am using echo %%i
it's printing %i only inside the loop
i want to check if whether particular csv file is there or not in the directory
so that's why i am trying to assigning file name only into the variable.

Comment: How do you know that a file isn't there?. Attention: Syntax is different on command line and batchfiles. On command line use `%i` syntax, inside batchfiles use `%%i` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This lists all the files (and only the files) in the current directory:

```
for /r %i in (*) do echo %i
```

Also if you run that command in a batch file you need to double the % signs.

```
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

try this:

```
::Example directory
set SetupDir=C:\Users

::Loop in the folder with "/r" to search in recursive folders, %%f being a loop ::variable 
for /r "%SetupDir%" %%f in (*.msi *.exe) do set /a counter+=1
```

`echo there are %counter%` files in your folder
it counts .msi and .exe files in your directory (and in the sub directory). So it also makes the difference between folders and files as executables.

Just add an extension (.pptx .docx ..) if you need to filter other files in the loop

Comment: C:\MM-cmd\INPUT\D1.csv
C:\MM-cmd\INPUT\D2.csv
C:\MM-cmd\INPUT\D3.csv


it's coming all the files with directory but i need filenames alone and i need set to a variable, after that i am going to do the if D1.csv is there or not in the directory

Comment: try `%%~nxi` for file**n**ame and e**x**tension only.

Comment: Thanks Stephan,
I am getting the filenames with extension, but while using the below for  loop
for /r %%i in (*.csv) do set xfilevar=%%~nxi
i am getting the last file name
but i need to get the filenames into a variable one by one

Comment: extend your loop: `for ..... do (`, then several lines containing your code, then `)` to close the loop.

Comment: I tried the below 
for /r %%i in (*.csv) do(
set xfilevar=%%~nxi
echo %xfilevar%
)

i am getting like this    "do( was unexpected at this time."